# laravel eloquent sum of related append column value

Tags: laravel

I have an appended column in my `CsmSales` model.

```
protected $appends = [
    'earnings'
];
```

Now when I pluck and dump the appended attribute "earnings":

```
$csm = CustomerSuccessManager::with([
        'csmSales.user:id,first_name,last_name',
        'user:id,first_name,last_name'
    ])->get();

    dd($csm[0]->csmSales->pluck('earnings'));
```

Got this values:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1985
#items: array:4 [
0 => "0.56"
1 => "0.68"
2 => "0.68"
3 => "1.08"
 ]
}
```

Is there a way to get the sum of that returned array using eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could work:

```
$csm[0]->csmSales->sum('earnings');
```

Comment: I did that and it works. However, I want to attach the data directly to my collection without needing to loop through $csm collection object.